# Device token for push notifications not generated

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, push-notification

Since a few days, I am unable to receive push notifications for one of my apps. I had a closer look and it seems it doesn't manage to generate a device token. I was able to reproduce it with a blank application and the following code (or the Swift equivalent):

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Granted.");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not granted.");
        }
    }];
    
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Token: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Push notifications were added to the app's capabilities (I've blanked out the team name and part of the certificate description):

[image]

and this generated the following entitlements file:

[image]

When the app launches, I get the usual popup:

[image]

and the app reaches the 'Granted' block:

```
2022-06-12 19:55:28.665018+0200 Sandbox[1704:108535] Granted.
```

but I see neither a device token nor an error in the log.

Comment: @Rob it always worked with a development build, but even if I use an ad-hoc profile (with APS environment set to `production`) it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes - I believe that's what the first screenshot shows.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I already switched Teams, using a different bundle identifier, tried using 4G instead of WiFi, using an iPad instead of an iPhone, all to no avail ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245538/discussion-between-rob-and-glorfindel).

Comment: After a few days, the problem resolved itself without any changes from my side. Probably Apple was having some problems internally :(